# XSL Using replace and matches to update values

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to update an old form that uses a data model that has changed, so any reference to the old model I want to replace with the new. I currently use the function **matches** to tell if I should preform the replace on the current string and then use the **replace** function to replace the value with the new one, the problem is that the regex used in the **matches** does not work with the regex in the **replace**.

```
 <xsl:template
    match="//*[contains(@*:default,'instance(''document'')/')
    mode="pass">

    <xsl:variable
        name="regex"
        as="element()*">
        <regex>instance('document')/doc_type/description</regex>
        <regex>anotherRegex</regex>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
        name="replacement"
        as="element()*">
        <replacement>xxf:get-request-parameter('documentDesc')</replacement>
        <replacement>replacedRegex</replacement>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name() = ('xxf:default')">
                    <xsl:attribute name="xxf:default">
                        <xsl:analyze-string
                        regex="{concat('(',$regex[1],'|',$regex[2],')')}"
                        select=".">
                            <xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:if test="matches(.,$regex[1])">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,$regex[1],$replacement[1])" />
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="matches(.,$regex[2])">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,$regex[2],$replacement[2])" />
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Current XML:

```
<xf:bind id="clinic-bind"
    name="clinic"
    xxf:default="instance('document')/doc_type/description"
    type="xf:string"/>
```

What I want to turn it into:

```
<xf:bind id="clinic-bind"
    name="clinic"
    xxf:default="xxf:get-request-parameter('documentDesc')"
    type="xf:string"/>
```

Comment: You need to escape some characters in regular expressions, like `()`. functx has a function for that.

Comment: Ahh yes, So I ended up finding out that something else in my style sheet was over riding this change, I was escaping the '()' characters and now It seems to work, I wasted a day on this! argh!

Answer (score 0):

So the Problem was basicaally I had to escape the '()' characters in the regex variable.

So I ended up with

```
<regex>instance\('document'\)/doc_type/description</regex>
```

In the regex part.